# Neo4J Delete Nodes With Field Value Not in CSV with Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello I want to delete all nodes with the label GRAPH_OBJECT that have a property value (lets call it myprop) that is not in a list of numeric values that I have in a CSV or text file.

How do a I accomplish this with Cypher?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
// load csv
LOAD CSV FROM "file://values.txt" AS row
// create a collection of the first column turned into numeric values
WITH collect(toInt(row[0])) AS blacklist
// find the nodes
MATCH (node:GRAPH_OBJECT) 
// for any of the properties of the node, if it's value is in our blacklist
WHERE ANY(property in keys(node) WHERE node[property] IN blacklist)
// delete node and relationships
DETACH DELETE node;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think the query should be a whitelist instead of a blacklist and we want to delete any node (with label GRAPH_OBJECT) that is not in the white list.  Also in my case, it's a specific property value 'myprop' so do I change this:  "WHERE ANY(property in keys(node) WHERE node[property] IN blacklist)"  to this:  "WHERE node.`myprop` NOT IN whitelist"   ?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Michael Hunger's code and updating with your comment, I believe this should work:

```
// load csv
LOAD CSV FROM "file://values.txt" AS row
// create a collection of the first column turned into numeric values
WITH collect(toInt(row[0])) AS whitelist
// find the nodes
MATCH (node:GRAPH_OBJECT) 
// for any of the properties of the node, if it's value is in our blacklist
WHERE NOT node.myprop IN whitelist)
// delete node and relationships
DETACH DELETE node;
```

The first WHERE clause in Michael's code (`WHERE ANY(property in keys(node)`) appears to just be there so each property on the node can be search, so if you only need to search myprop then this should not be needed.

Answer (score 0):

This should work quite fast as I also use Index. Firstly, you can create an index on the property that you use as a reference to compare the nodes in the CSV. 
In your case,

```
CREATE INDEX ON :GRAPH_OBJECT(myprop)
```

Then, you can do something like this to delete those node which are not present in the CSV but in your Database.

```
LOAD CSV FROM "file://values.csv" AS line
WITH collect(line.myprop) AS blacklist
//Assuming there is a header in the CSV with 'myprop' value which compare your existing database node with this property
MATCH (node:GRAPH_OBJECT) 
WHERE EXISTS (node.myprop)
AND
NOT node.myprop IN blacklist
DETACH DELETE node;
```

That's it, You can add a PROFILE to see how well the query performs using Index